# How to use bootstrap-icons with Rails 7.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use bootstrap-icons in my Rails 7.0 app, but icons are collapsed.

[image]

It should display "plus" icon (This image is in my old app).

[image]

I'm also getting ActionController::RoutingError.

```
08:05:31 web.1  | Started GET "/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2?30af91bf14e37666a085fb8a161ff36d" for ::1 at 2021-12-30 08:05:31 +0900
08:05:31 web.1  |   
08:05:31 web.1  | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2"):
08:05:31 web.1  |   
08:05:31 web.1  | Started GET "/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff?30af91bf14e37666a085fb8a161ff36d" for ::1 at 2021-12-30 08:05:31 +0900
08:05:31 web.1  |   
08:05:31 web.1  | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff"):
```

Here are steps I did:

1. Created a new app by `rails new my-app-name --css bootstrap`
2. Ran `npm i bootstrap-icons` (then I got `"bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2"` in my `package.json`)
3. Edited `app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss` like this:

   ```
     @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
     @import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
     @import 'custom';
   ```
4. Wrote erb like this:

   ```
     <%= link_to new_project_path, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
       <i class="bi bi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       New Project
     <% end %>
   ```
5. Started my app by `bin/dev`

I read these pages but couldn't resolve the error;

- https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage
- https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/issues/22
- https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/476

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for me.

Run these commands;

```
npm i bootstrap-icons
npm i copyfiles
mkdir public/fonts
touch public/fonts/.keep
echo "/public/fonts/*" >> .gitignore
echo "\!/public/fonts/.keep" >> .gitignore
```

Add this line to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss` .

```
@import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
```

Edit "build:css" script in `package.json` like this.

```
"build:css": "copyfiles -f node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/* public/fonts && sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```

Start up server with `bin/dev` command then the bootstrap icons appeared!

[image]

### EDIT

I found much simpler solution.

Install bootstrap-icons.

```
npm i bootstrap-icons
```

Add this line to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss`.

```
@import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
```

Edit `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font")
```

Start up server with `bin/dev` command. That's all!

### EDIT2

> I'm trying a similar approach with FontAwesome and Tailwind. However, the fonts are not found in my browser. For example: http://localhost:4000/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2. Are you able to share an example path that is used with the bootstrap fonts? Thanks.

I could use FontAwesome like this:

Install npm.

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Add the following line to `app/javascript/application.js` .

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"
```

Edit ERB.

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

Start up server with bin/dev command.

[image]

But I'm not sure about Tailwind.

Comment: See https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/issues/63
Many thanks @junichi :top:

Comment: @viktorianer Thank you for letting me know. That's a good idea!

Comment: I'm trying a similar approach with FontAwesome and Tailwind. However, the fonts are not found in my browser. For example: `http://localhost:4000/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2`. Are you able to share an example path that is used with the bootstrap fonts? Thanks.

Comment: @Marklar I could use FontAwesome. Please refer my answer.

Comment: @JunichiIto thanks for taking the time to share your solution. I notice you're importing into `application.js`. Does this mean you're using webpacker to server your css if this example?

Comment: @Marklar No. I don't use webpacker. I guess it comes from jsbuilding-rails and esbuild. You can find my sample app here: https://github.com/JunichiIto/everydayrails-rspec-jp-2022

Comment: @JunichiIto Thanks. That makes sense. I was looking for a full cssbundling-rails approach, but was confused seeing as it needed to go in `application.js`. I've moved on for now and will simply use the Font Awesome CDN kits.

Comment: the second solution currently does not work when using propshaft for asset loading on rails 7. see https://github.com/rails/propshaft/issues/101

Comment: This works for the font based icons, but not for the sprites. To get the sprites working I just added Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/") to assets, then I can use the stripes like so: <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use href="/assets/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons#house"></use></svg>

Comment: @JunichiIto, thanks a ton for this thorough answer; figuring out the asset pipeline is a huge pain, and you drastically simplified it! The Internet will be using this answer for years (and all the AI crawlers )

Answer (score 2):

In `application.scss` you can simply import

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a font-face in your scss file?

I have this below my imports

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2") format("woff2"), font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I still get the same error.